# Open Attached File with Link

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm trying to attach a non-pdf file to my pdf document, and open the file in the user's default program when a link is clicked.  The [help material for Acrobat](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/links-attachments-pdfs.html#link_to_a_file_attachment) describes how to link to a certain page in an attached file, but I'm assuming that only works if the attached file is also a pdf.  I was looking around in the link options, and the closest I saw to what I want would be to open the attachments panel when the user clicks the link.  However, I plan to have many files attached, with each file only relevant to a small part of my document.  I also saw an option to open a file with a link, but when I try to do that, it asks me to browse though the files on my computer.  I didn't see any options to open a file that was attached to the document.

Is there any way I can create a link that will open a specific file attached to my pdf document?

Comment: FWIW, the file I'm trying to attach is a Google Earth .kmz file.  When the user clicks the link, I want it to launch Google Earth with the file I attach loaded (assuming Google Earth is installed on the users machine, ofc).

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the [File Annotation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7e7f.w.html). When extracting a File Annotation, you have the option to make it open with its associated (on the user's machine) application.

There are some security restrictions, but I think a .kmz file should work.

More about File Annotations in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up being able to host the file I needed on my server, and used the web link option instead of the open file option when creating the link in my document, and that is working for my needs.  I'll check this out when I get an opportunity and upvote and accept if it works.